# Retrieve a List of all the CAWA Applications

Tags: automation, job-scheduling, ca, workload

I want to get a list of all the applications that exist in the CA Workload Automation system programmatically. I've seen all kinds of commands on the internet that supposedly answer what I'm looking for but I can't figure out how to use them (things like [LISTAPPL](https://techdocs.broadcom.com/us/en/ca-mainframe-software/automation/ca-workload-automation-esp-edition/12-0/reference/commands/listappl-command-list-applications.html) command or [Retrieve the List of all Applications using REST API](https://techdocs.broadcom.com/us/en/ca-enterprise-software/intelligent-automation/ca-workload-automation-de-web-client/12-4/reference/rest-api-examples/retrieve-the-list-of-all-applications.html)).

I would be happy if someone could tell me how to use the existing commands, or even if there is a way to "scrape" the data from the software's files (in the end it must sit somewhere on my machine).

I thank anyone who can help me with this.